# Getting address components from a Google Maps place search

Tags: json, google-maps

When calling the Google Maps [Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests) with this request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=The+White+House&key=[REDACTED]
```

I get a JSON array of results, that looks like this (edited to remove noise):

```
  {
     "formatted_address" : "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC 20500, United States",
     "geometry" : { /* lng/lat */ },
     "id" : "961fbdc3bf1fb3969cbf6421e9ebde0d837b8496",
     "name" : "The White House",
     "place_id" : "ChIJ37HL3ry3t4kRv3YLbdhpWXE",
  }
```

Which is fine, but I need to break out `formatted_address` into its parts: street number, route, locality, etc. Is there a way to do that with this one query, or perhaps a different one?

I could look up the `place_id` with a [separate API call](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details#PlaceDetailsRequests), but that could lead to an n+1 situation in my case... which wouldn't be ideal.

Reverse geocoding based on the longitude/latitude isn't helpful because I already know the place I'm looking for, and the results typically generates a long list that I have to walk through to match against the `formatted_address` provided by the initial search. It also leads to the n+1 issue that the Place API has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you guessed, you need to make the separate [Place Details Request](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details#PlaceDetailsRequests).  There's no way to get `address_components` in search results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Geocoder service. It takes in partially completed addresses and postcodes too.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderAddressComponent

Comment: Reverse geocoding yields worse results than looking up the `place_id`.

Comment: I meant _forward_ Geocoding - replace the Place Search API call with the Geocoding service. Look up The White House and it returns a list of results just like Place Search.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple